# GHCI vs Prelude command prompt in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to learn Haskell from the beginning and was wondering what exactly is the difference between the two prompts (Haskell and Prelude) that are used in it. It may sound a very naive question and not to mention I tried searching for the answer before posting this question but couldn't find one (proper one). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, if I'm understanding this correctly, you're wondering if there's a difference between

```
Prelude>
```

and

```
ghci>
```

as prompts after you've invoked GHCi from the command line.

If this is the case, then there is no real difference aside from preference. You can change the prompt to whatever you want to by using the command:

```
:set prompt "aglebargle> "
```

You can replace `arglebargle>` with whatever you'd like.

The main advantage I see for the `Prelude>` prompt is that it will update when you import modules. Prelude is the only module you have without any imports, which is why it's the prompt. E.g., if you, say, did `import Control.Monad`, you'd get `Prelude Control.Monad>` as a prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But while reading about Haskell, I came across a statement in the introduction chapter -  **"The prompt here is Prelude> but because it can get longer when you load stuff into the session, we're going to use ghci>"**. Does using ghci prompt over prelude have any implications over loading time?

Comment: The prompt is only informational / aesthetic; it doesn't affect loading time, but it can get rather long and take up a large portion of the line if you're in a narrow window. The only loss when changing to a fixed prompt is that you will have to remember which packages have been imported instead of being able to look at them in the prompt.

Comment: If you want to know which things you have imported but also keep the prompt short, you should try importing as. I.e., `import Control.Monad as CM` will give you a prompt that looks like `Prelude CM> `. (You don't have to use `CM.function` either because you haven't `import qualified`.)

Answer (score 1):

The prompt indicates which module(s) is being worked on and since the Prelude is a standard module for Haskell from GHC it is shown explicitly as the first prompt. However from GHC version 9.x the Prelude is loaded implicitly (unless some directive to the contrary has been given) so the prompt from now on is just "ghci>".
By the way, the Prelude module contains a set of basic types, type classes, and functions to use at the start of any Haskell project without needing to define everything from the beginning.

Comment: Prelude was always imported by default in all versions of GHC, nothing has changed here.